# Generate 10MHz clock in Artix-7 FPGA series

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado

This is a question from a FPGA newbie. I have a simple Verilog for a counter and I would like to generate a clock for it.

Can I generate a 10MHz clock in FPGA without an external clock source?
How can generate it?

PLL/MMCM seems to work just with external clock sources.

Thanks in advance
Jorge Johanny

Comment: Yes, FPGAs require external clock sources. Fortunately, any FPGA evaluation board you can buy will have at least one clock oscillator included. Use the PLL/MMCM to change the frequency if necessary.

Comment: You need and external clock source. As already mentioned, all eval boards already have these fitted (for this reason).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all a matter of clock precision. If you can afford a +/- 50% (500000 ppm) frequency tolerance on your 10 MHz clock, then yes, this is doable without relying on any external clock.

There is a primitive in 7-series, called STARTUPE2, that outputs the internal oscillator (the internal clock used by internal configuration logic in master modes). For Artix-7, this clock is specified in datasheet ([DS181](https://docs.xilinx.com/v/u/en-US/ds181_Artix_7_Data_Sheet), table 66) as being 65 MHz Typical, with +/- 50% tolerance (see FCFGMCLK, FCFGMCLKTOL).

You can pipe it to MMCM or PLL and get an output of 10 Mhz Typ., but tolerance of 50% wont change.